# Not able to click on drop down option in a ajax webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, onclick

I am able to click on the drop down heading but not able to click on the options. Also I am not able to identify the 'id' or xpath for options which is visible after clicking the dropdown option.

Find the HTML below:

```
<div id="object260310" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background: transparent; z-index: 50; left: 154px; top: 5px; width: 74px; height: 20px;">
  <div id="object351" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 74px; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 42px;">
      <div role="menu" aria-label="1" class="font89" style="padding-left: 0px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; left: 0px; color: rgb(126, 126, 126); width: 43px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; background: transparent;" onclick="plw.menu.click(this,351,0,&quot;1&quot;,true);" onmouseenter="plw.menu.over(event,this,351,0,&quot;1&quot;);this.style.color=&quot;rgb(174,174,174)&quot;;this.style.backgroundColor=&quot;rgb(255,255,255)&quot;" onmouseleave="plw.menu.out(351);this.style.background=&quot;transparent&quot;;this.style.color=&quot;rgb(126,126,126)&quot;;">
        <div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:2px" class="image347 "></div>
        <span style="position:relative;left:21px;top:0px">New</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my selenium code:

```
new_create = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until( EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div')))
driver.find_element_by_id("object260310").click()
#its working fine till here

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@onclick, '231')]").click() 
#This line doesnt seems to work.
```

And here is a [screenshot of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttQu4.png).

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am not able to click options in the dropdown .

Comment: I don't see `@onclick, '231' ` anywhere from the HTML you have posted

Comment: @Pradeephebbar You are right . This is also one of the issue it changes some of the time ,in the HTML I posted its '351'. onclick="plw.menu.click(this,351,0,&quot;1&quot;,true); Any help is greatly appreciated . I am just trying to click the options in dropdown . I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: @ManishKumar You can click based on the value in that case , Which value are you trying to select from dropdown?

Comment: @Pradeephebbar I am not able to see any value in the HTML . I think its not specified .Can you help if you see anything as such in snippet

Comment: @ManishKumar   Can you please tell me what is that new in your HTML code

Comment: @Pradeephebbar New is the heading of the dropdown . It has got four options namely 'Product Variation','cross product variation','Group','template' . But I am not able to find dropdown option specified anywhere in HTML

Comment: Drop-down options will be there and it might be hidden, once u click on the drop-down it will be visible. try to check complete html, you may find the html for drop-down options

Comment: Is your drop-down node is `div` or `select` or `span`, Please specify.

Comment: @Pradeephebbar Its div. I have updated image link of the HTML above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I was able to find the xpath using chrome XPATH Helper extension.Extension gave below xpath :

```
/html/body/div[@id='m235e0-SUB-1']/table[@class='oldmenu']/tbody/tr[@id='235-0-SUB-1-1']/td[@class='oldmenu']
```

Using this I was able to identify the id for sub menu i.e. '235-0-SUB-1-1'

So I modified the code accordingly as below :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="235-0-SUB-1-1"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking drop down options have been iffy for me before. This is a thing I do when there aren't any other solutions:

Click the drop down then you can send keys depending on the letter of the option you need. so if an option is "action" then you press "a".

This highly depends on what you have in the drop down though.

EDIT: I would highly look at all the related questions there... They have some stuff you might be able to use. As I said this is only if those don't work!

Comment: You can check the code snippet I just posted. I am not able to identify the id or xpath for menu option

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to click on the drop-down first(New in your case)
2. If the dropdown is not `select` , then use the below code select the value.

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text(),'Product Variation']").click();
   ```

Comment: @ManishKumar , If you can try to add some more attribute check to xpath and make it unique , it would be great

Comment: I am able to click drop down and the options are displayed but I am not able to click next option I tried your code but its throwing error . SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[text(),'Product Variation']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Xpath may not be be a correct, but its a valid one.

Comment: OK thanks a lot buddy . I will look if I am missing some thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Product Variation']").click();
```

Think the xpath should be written that way. Will you send me the URL and I'll make sure I can click before I make another edit on this post?

Comment: Thank you for your concern but I will have to share id , pwd along with URL then only you will be able to access the page.But I cannt share that. Any way below id the link of the image of the page and relevant HTML , hope it helps https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttQu4.png

Comment: Its Planisware software